# Delete order line Items in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce plugin in wordpress & and place it inside            `/home/builhsqv/public_html/test/wp-contents/plugins/` location. Now I have created a php file in `/home/builhsqv/public_html/test/test.php`. Inside this file I have written my code to delete an individual Order line item.

```
<strong>
//TEST.PHP
<?php   
error_reporting(E_ALL );
require_once( dirname(__FILE__)."/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-order-functions.php");
echo "Woocommerce";
$itemID = 1234;
echo $result = wc_delete_order_item($itemID);
print_r($result);  die;
?>

//wc-order-functions.php (File of woocommerce with function body)
<?php
function wc_delete_order_item( $item_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $item_id = absint( $item_id );
    if ( ! $item_id )
        return false;
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_delete_order_item', $item_id );
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "DELETE FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_item_id = %d", $item_id ) );
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "DELETE FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta WHERE order_item_id = %d", $item_id ) );
    do_action( 'woocommerce_delete_order_item', $item_id );
    return true;
}
?>
</strong>
```

When I run this file in the browser, it's showing a blank page.
But when I comment the require path and the calling function that I can see the echo message.

I want to deleted a order line item using the PHP script in woocommerce.

Answer (score 1):

Need first to know your order line ids.

I get them like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT woi.order_item_name, woim.meta_value, woim.order_item_id
    FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items woi JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta woim
    WHERE order_id = ' . $order_id . '
    AND woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id AND woim.meta_key = \'_product_id\'
    GROUP BY woi.order_item_name ORDER BY 3';
```

I load them in a table. And when I want to delete lines I use this function:

```
function order_delete_lines($lines) {
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        wc_delete_order_item($line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find this file in WooCommerce requires others from the plugin and WordPress itself to remove the order item.

Though I am not sure why you would be doing this with a script for 1 line item of 1 order when this can be done via the CMS or database, to use WooCommerce helper functions copy index.php, and change `WP_USE_THEMES` to `false` like so.

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );

/** Delete order line item 1234 */
$itemID = 1234;
$result = wc_delete_order_item($itemID);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

This will achieve what you are trying to do as long as you store in the root of your WordPress installation.

I stumbled across this looking to remove all items relating to a order ID without querying the database directly, which after digging though WooCommerce code for anybody else looking for the same resulted in

```
$order_id = 123456;
$order    = new WC_Order($order_id);

foreach ($order->get_items() as $order_item_id => $item){ 
    wc_delete_order_item($order_item_id);
}
```